# How to filter a many to many relationship by a column in pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

My application has the following entities:

- `Locations`
- `Disciplines`
- `Instructors`

`Disciplines` and `Instructors` should be a many to many relationship, so in my `Discipline` model I have the following:

```php
public function instructors() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Instructor::class,
        'location_discipline_instructors',
        'discipline_id',
        'instructor_id'
    );
}
```

My `pivot` table contains the following fields:

- `location_id`
- `discipline_id`
- `instructor_id`

I can use this relationship to fetch all `disciplines` with the associated `instructors`, but I need to filter these results by the `location_id` in the `pivot` table.

How should I approach this?

Comment: The answer is well written in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#filtering-queries-via-intermediate-table-columns

Comment: @MaartenVeerman I have tried wherePivot('location_id', 1) - I've hard coded a value for testing purposes, but I end up with a list of all disciplines with their instructors - I want only disciplines that are associated with the location_id form the pivot table

Comment: @Josh use `withPivot` again, but instead of doing `->get()` or something like that, do `->toSql()` and share the resulting query with us. To share it, update your question, do not post it here as a comment, please.

Comment: @matiaslauriti Thank you, I've solved this problem and added an answer with my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using `wherePivot()` with `location_id`, but with that approach, I ended up with a list of all system `disciplines` with `instructors` for any `discipline` that had `instructors` associated. I continued to research and ended up with this solution:

```
Discipline::whereHas('instructors', function ($query) {
    return $query->where('location_id', '=', $this->locationId);
})->with('instructors')->get();
```